# Filter Rows If The First Sign Change Is Detected In A Column By Group In Python

Tags: python, lambda

I have a dataframe:

```
col1 col2 group
10   1     A
11   2     A
12  -2     A
13  -3     B
14   3     B
```

How do I choose rows if there is a **first sign change** in `col2` by `group`.

For instance, for the first unique value of `group` ('A'), the first sign change (`+` to `-`) occurs at the third row (`col1`=12 and `col2` = -2).

**Desired result**:

```
col1 col2 group
12  -2    A
14   3    B
```

```
data = {
    'col1': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 
    'col2': [1, 2, -2, -3, 3],
    'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']
    }  
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

ind = []


def my_func(x):
    if x.loc[x.index[0], 'col2'] < 0:
        ind.append(x[x['col2'] >= 0].index[0])
    else:
        ind.append(x[x['col2'] < 0].index[0])


df.groupby('group').apply(my_func)

df1 = df.loc[ind]

print(df1)
```

Output

```
   col1  col2 group
2    12    -2     A
4    14     3     B
```

The dataframe is grouped by the 'group' column. In the my_func function, it is checked if the first number is negative, then we are looking for the first non-negative one, we get its index. In else: opposite condition. Indexes are written to the ind list, which is then substituted into the dataframe to select the desired rows. Explicit [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc) indexing is used.

Below is a variant with lambda:

```
bbb = df.groupby('group').apply(
    lambda x: x[x['col2'] >= 0].index[0] if x.loc[x.index[0], 'col2'] < 0 else x[x['col2'] < 0].index[0])

df1 = df.loc[bbb.values]

print(df1)
```